# Send Parallel data over ConnectionId's in Dot Net Core 2.2 SignalR

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr

I'm trying to implement SignalR with Angular, I want to send data to all ConnectionsIds.
I have Mapped each Connection Id to SectionId having 1-to-Many Relation as below,

```
public Class SectionConnectionMapping{
    public string SectionId {get; set:}
    public List<string> ConnectionId {get; Set;}
}
```

I want to Fetch SectionRelated data from DB and `SendAsync` to mapped ConnectionsIds parallelly,

```
Parallel.For(0, SectionConnectionMapping.Count, index => {
    _hubContext.Clients.Clients(SectionConnectionMapping[index].Connections).SendAsync("SendMessage",
        new {
            somVal = getPatientData(SectionConnectionMapping[index].SectionId),
        })
});
```

But it is throwing an exception as below,

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext, however instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe. This could also be caused by a nested query being evaluated on the client, if this is the case rewrite the query avoiding nested invocations.'`

If I Make `for loop` sequential, it works fine, but how can I make it parallel.

I have added Context in Startup.cs as,

```
services.AddDbContext<CustomContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

Also implemented it in DI of that Service as,

```
public class LiveHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly CustomContext _context;
    public LiveHostedService(CustomContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EntityFramework DbContext is not a thread-safe. This means it can not execute multiple queries at the same time.

`getPatientData(SectionConnectionMapping[index].SectionId)` is executing multiple times on same EF DbContext. Prepare data separately and then pass to `_hubContext.Clients.Clients.SendAsync`, or create a new instance of EF DbContext.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. what is `Prepare data separately`? Can you explain a little bit? & How to do it?

Comment: avoid `getPatientData(SectionConnectionMapping[index].SectionId)` in parallel. if you want to use in parallel make sure `getPatientData` uses new EF DbContext